# Pattern matching against Just containing a pair

Tags: haskell

I'm experimenting with Haskell and I'm wondering why I couldn't match against a Just containing a pair. I have little experience with this language and I'm completely lost.

```
f :: Int -> Maybe (Int, [Int])
f 100 = Nothing
f x = Just (x,[x])

g :: Int -> Maybe Int
g x
 | u==Nothing = Nothing
 | u==(Just (r,s)) = Just r
 where 
  u=f x
```

So what is wrong with this code. GHC says that `r` and `s` are not in scope.

Comment: Scoping issues aside, using `==` would introduce an `Eq` constraint that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the guard expression can't do pattern matching.

Guard expression is just like a boolean expression, it can't do binding. It just uses the binding before `|`, in this case `x`.

So working solution will be like this.

```
g :: Int -> Maybe Int
g x = case f x of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just (r,_) -> Just r
```

Comment: *"Because the guard expression…"*. What about `g x | Just (r,s) <- u = …`? You can bind/match in a guard. You just have to use the correct syntax. `==` isn't correct.

Comment: @Zeta I just didn't know that `PatternGuard` is default as of Haskell2010. Thanks for notification. I'll leave my answer for Haskell98 case and your answer already posted.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to pattern match in a guard, you have to use a [pattern guard](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard):

```
g :: Int -> Maybe Int
g x
  | Just (r,_) <- u = Just r
  | otherwise       = Nothing 
  where 
   u = f x
```

After all, `(==)` is a regular function, you need values on both sides to use it. Since `r` and `s` aren't known in `u == Just (r,s)`, the compiler gives you your error message.

By the way, taking a `Maybe` and return `Nothing` if the value was `Nothing` or `Just (h x)` for a function `h` and `Just x` is so common, it forms a pattern: `fmap`. You can write

```
g :: Int -> Maybe Int
g x = fmap fst (f x)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [case expressions](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html)

```
g :: Int -> Maybe Int
g x =
  case f x of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just (r,s) -> Just r
```